# Setting Edges / Borders of ImageView Transparent Android

Tags: java, android, transparency, overlapping, alpha-transparency

I would like to set the edges of an ImageView transparent.
I know how to set a whole ImageView to transparent like I did in my code below.  However, Is there any way that I can set **only** the edges / border of the image to transparent? E.g. I want 70% (the interior) of an ImageView to be normal while the remaining 30% (the outside) should be transparent.
My aim is to overlap two images (clouds and birds), so that I can see the birds "flying" around the clouds while maintaing the clouds original color.

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ImageView clouds;
    ImageView birds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);

        clouds = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cloudView);
        birds = (ImageView)findViewBy(R.id.birdView);

        clouds.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudsImage);
        birds.setImageResource(R.drawable.birdsImage);

        clouds.setAlpha(0.5f);
    }
}
```

Would highly appreciate any help on this matter!

Comment: you can change the alpha value

Answer (score 0):

> My aim is to overlap two images (clouds and birds), so that I can see the birds "flying" around the clouds while maintaing the clouds original color

If your background isn't necessary to be `ImageView` you can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/clouds">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/flying_bird"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```